# $this->l("Descripcion del modulo") return empty string

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am creating a new module for prestashop.
I am using the prestashop guide and when I try to set this:

```
class MiModulo extends Module{    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->name = "mimodulo";
        $this->tab = "front_office_features";
        $this->version = "1.0.0";
        $this->author = "Ivan Javier Barranco Gavilan";
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array("min" => "1.6", "max" => _PS_VERSION_ );
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l("Mi Modulo");
        $this->description = $this->l("Descripcion del modulo");

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l("¿Esta seguro de que desea desinstalar el modulo?");

        if(!Configuration::get("mimodulo"))
            $this->warning = $this->l("Sin nombre proporcionado");
    }
}
```

::l(), according to prestashop it is a function that translates text strings, but not where it should introduce these translations.

$this->l() always returns an empty string.

I have an installation of prestashop in spanish.
How I should make the translations correctly? Thanks!

Comment: what is `::l()`? we need more info please.

Comment: oki , i go to update my ask

Answer (score 0):

> Go to the "Translations" page under the "Localization" menu, In the "Modify translations" drop-down menu, choose "Installed modules translations", Choose the language you want to translate the module into.
>
> The destination language must already be installed to enable translation in it. Click the "Modify" button.
>
> The page that loads displays all the strings for all the currently-installed modules. Modules that have all their strings already translated have their fieldset closed, whereas if at least one string is missing in a module's translation, its fieldset is expanded.
>
> In order to translate your module's strings (the ones that were "marked" using the l() method), simply find your module in the list (use the browser's in-page search), and fill the empty fields.
>   Once all strings for your module are correctly translated, click on either the "Save and stay" button or the "Save" button at the bottom of your list of strings.
>
> PrestaShop then saves the translations in a new file, named using the languageCode.php format (for instance, /mymodule/fr.php).

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Module+translation